# Cplex linking Error in Mex Command from Matlab

Tags: mex, cplex

### I am trying to run mixed integer quadratic programming by calling Cplex (122version) from Matlab using Mex function.   When I try in matlab : mex miqp_cplex.c, following type errors occurred.

Creating library C:\Users\maskamal\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3XVWAG\templib.x and object C:\Users\maskamal\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3XVWAG\templib.exp 
miqp_cplex.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CPXcloseCPLEX referenced in function miqp 
miqp_cplex.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CPXfreeprob referenced in function miqp 
miqp_cplex.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CPXgetmipitcnt referenced in function miqp 
miqp_cplex.mexw64 : fatal error LNK1120: 21 unresolved externals

### C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2011A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Link of 'miqp_cplex.mexw64' failed.

Since it fail to locate "ilcplex\cplex.h", I add full path

## include "C:\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_AcademicResearch122\cplex\include\ilcplex\cplex.h" and I guess problem is related to cplex.h and linking with library.

Any hints to solve my problem are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it partly. I could compile by adding the path of library with mex command. However, when I run the mex file: miqp_cplex it says:
 Invalid MEX-file 'C:\Users\maskamal\Documents\MATLAB\MexCplex80\miqp_cplex.mexw64': 指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。(translation from japanese: indicated module is not found)

My Matlab R2011a and Cplex122